# Javascript Inheritance codecademy

Tags: javascript, inheritance

With the code given below, I'm trying to output the value and type of choc and I'm getting undefined for type and milk for chocolate. Can someone please help me understand how to output the type? I've been working on this for awhile and it's not clicking to me. Thanks!

```
// we set up a base class
function Candy() {
    this.sweet = true;
}

// create a "Chocolate" class with a "type" argument
Chocolate = function(type){
    this.type = type;
};

// say that Chocolate inherits from Candy

Chocolate.prototype = new Candy();

// create a "choc" object using the Chocolate constructor 
// that has a "type" of "milk"

var choc = new Object();
choc.type = "milk";

// print the sweet and type properties of choc
console.log(choc.sweet);
console.log(choc.type);
```

//////this is what I changed it to and still doesnt work//////////

```
// we set up a base class
function Candy() {
    this.sweet = true;
}

// create a "Chocolate" class with a "type" argument
Chocolate = function(type){
    this.type = type;
};

// say that Chocolate inherits from Candy

Chocolate.prototype = new Candy();

// create a "choc" object using the Chocolate constructor 
// that has a "type" of "milk"

var choc = new Chocolate();
choc.type = "milk";

// print the sweet and type properties of choc
console.log(choc.sweet);
console.log(choc.type);
```

Comment: Why do you use the `Object` constructor but say you would use the `Chocolate` constructor?

Comment: You say "print the sweet property", but you code `.value`.

Comment: I changed it to Chocolate constructor on codecademy but still doesnt work.

Comment: I ran the second half (in Chrome) of what you posted, and that works for me. I get outputs of `true`, and then `milk`.

Comment: You should accept the correct answer to your question, if it worked for you.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the last four lines of your code (it does not use anything from above):

```
// create a "choc" object using the Chocolate constructor 
// that has a "type" of "milk"

var choc = new Object();
choc.type = "milk";

// print the sweet and type properties of choc
console.log(choc.value);
console.log(choc.type);
```

Neither did you create a `Chocolate` object, nor did you print the `sweet` property (therefore getting `undefined` for `value`).

Instead, use

```
var choc = new Chocolate("milk");
console.log(choc.sweet); // true
console.log(choc.type); // "milk"
```

Your updated code works for me.

Comment: you are correct, while you were typing that I did try it. It still has the same results.

Comment: @MrNart: Your edited code works perfectly fine for me. Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: Thanks guys, I just refreshed and it worked. Thanks for the help!